# cosine similarity vs raw angle as distance measure of two vectors

Tags: measure-theory, trigonometry, unit-of-measure

This is another seemingly stupid question, but it seems counter-intuitive for me to use a cosine of the angle as a similarity measure (in direction) of two vectors as opposed to the angle itself.

To elaborate, when we take the similarity of vectors v1, v2 and v3
we would expect some linearity in the measure, for example d(v1,v2)+d(v2,v3) = d(v1,v3). A property cosine measures do not have; We are only taking one component in a 2D space.

Do we just use the cosine of the angle for convenience, because we do not want to define and redefine the range of the (negative vs positive) angles? Or is there another, deeper interpretation?

edit: changed "distance" to "similarity in direction"

Comment: Probably depends on the context, but I don't think there's a universally agreed upon default distance/similarity between vectors. In practice people change up what distance they use depending on the properties they want for a given application. Also I have the impression you're talking about $\mathbb R^2$, if you go to higher dimensions and have cartesian coordinates, the cosine is quite easy to compute using scalar product, whereas the angle is not. So that may be one reason to favor cosine?

Comment: The cosine of the angle between vectors does *NOT* measure the distance between them in any way. It measures the extent of parallelness they share. If they point in the same direction, they are perfectly parallel (and the cosine is $1$); if they are at right angles to each other, they are perfectly perpendicular -- not at all parallel (and the cosine is $0$).

Comment: @MPW Well, cosine still works as a measure of similarity for their direction? Also I'd prefer $\lvert\cos\rvert$ for what you describe as a measure of parallelness (a cosine of $-1$ also indicates parallelism).

Comment: Yes, the cosine carries additional information about direction in the sign. I was speaking in simplest terms.

Comment: `we would expect some linearity in the measure, for example d(v1,v2)+d(v2,v3) = d(v1,v3)` Not necessarily when working with angles. For example $v_1,v_3$ could be collinear (or even identical) and $v_2$ orthogonal to both.